# Can anyone tell me why my sqlite statement won't work?

Tags: java, sqlite

I have tried everything that i can think of with this SQLite statement. i have the following code that I am trying to run.

```
public ArrayList getData(int i)
{
    data = new ArrayList();

    try
    {
        Statement stat2;
        stat2 = conn.createStatement();
        System.out.println(i);
        PreparedStatement prep9 = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM tbl_INPUT_OBJECTS WHERE cardID = ?;");
        prep9.setInt(1, i);


        ResultSet rs2 = prep9.executeQuery();
        while (rs2.next())
        {
            System.out.println(3);
            IOdevice.get("IOdevice" + (rs2.getInt("id") - (16 * (i - 1)))).setId(rs2.getInt("id") - (16 * (i - 1)));
            IOdevice.get("IOdevice" + (rs2.getInt("id") - (16 * (i - 1)))).setDescription(rs2.getString("description"));

            System.out.println(4);

            System.out.println(rs2.getString("description"));
            System.out.println(rs2.getInt("id") - (16 * (i - 1)));
            System.out.println(IOdevice.get("IOdevice" + (rs2.getInt("id") - (16 * (i - 1)))));
            System.out.println(rs2.getBoolean("state"));
            System.out.println(rs2.getString("type"));
            System.out.println("IOdevice" + (rs2.getInt("id") - (16 * (i - 1))));

            IOdevice.get("IOdevice" + (rs2.getInt("id") - (16 * (i - 1)))).setState(rs2.getBoolean("state"));
            IOdevice.get("IOdevice" + (rs2.getInt("id") - (16 * (i - 1)))).setType(rs2.getString("type"));
        }

        rs2.close();
        stat2.close();

        System.out.println(5);
......etc.
```

my database that i am looking at is this:
[image: DB_ScreenShot]

my output from this part of the program is:

```
1
5
```

it should be:

```
1
3
4
5
```

can anybody give me advice as to what I'm doing wrong?

NOTE: the following code does work so it is not the database itself...(At least I don't think it is.)

```
Statement stat;
        stat = conn.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = stat
                .executeQuery("SELECT * from tbl_TEST WHERE cardID = " + i
                        + ";");
        while (rs.next())
        {
            data.add(rs.getInt("id"));
            data.add(rs.getString("lblDescriptionProp"));
            data.add(rs.getString("lblAddressProp"));
            data.add(IOdevice);

            for (int j = 1; j <= 32; j++)
            {
                IOdevice.get("IOdevice" + j).getDescription();
                IOdevice.get("IOdevice" + j).getState();
                IOdevice.get("IOdevice" + j).getType();
            }
        }

        rs.close();
        stat.close();
```

Comment: if there is anything else i can provide then let me know

Comment: @Razvan no, i haven't specified any types as I think I was having trouble with that earlier (That might have just been the hey it's the end of the work day so i'm going to epically fail thing though)

Comment: Could you test to just remove the semicolon from the query?

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson sure, give me min. edit: Nope same thing

Comment: P.S. I do have a catch after this to give back any exceptions but I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: where do you call the function getData() ?

Comment: Show us table `tbl_INPUT_OBJECTS` DDL, because I suspect cardID is `CHAR`.

Comment: @Razvan it gets called from my data class which then sends it to my 'GUI' Class. (I'm using the Model-View-Controller Design Pattern(detailed in "advanced actionscript 3 with design patterns" book))   In this case the getData class is being called with i == 1

Comment: @RosdiKasim Sorry for my ignorance but where whould i find that?

Comment: @Dylan DDL is the SQL CREATE STATEMENT of your table. Something like `CREATE TABLE tbl_INPUT_OBJECTS...` I can see only it partially in your screenshot.

Comment: @RosdiKasim I'd be surprised if that were the problem, SQLite doesn't strictly enforce data types anyway, and from looking at the create statement no type is specified so default affinity is NUMERIC

Comment: @RosdiKasim here is code used to create table:    stat2.executeUpdate("create table tbl_INPUT_OBJECTS (date, changeState, cardID, state, type, description, id);");
    prep2 = conn .prepareStatement("insert into tbl_INPUT_OBJECTS values (1342619157000, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");

Comment: NOTE:The Number is only added to the first row

Comment: @Dylan, James has rule that out.. anyway you should put that DDL in your question, not in the comment.

Comment: ....sorry...(I was thinking i couldn't edit question more because you can only edit comments 5 min. after creation)

Comment: It's probably worth debugging and inspecting exactly what prep9 and rs2 are after each line. Might shed some light on which line is failing.

Comment: I got it, Rosdi Kasim was partially correct, I think the default data type is numeric/string and i think it was refering to it as a string as when i changed the type manually through database browser to numeric and reran applet it started working. so thank you @RosdiKasim , If you put up answer then I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it works? I had the same problem not too long ago and it turned out the datatype was declared as `CHAR` in the table (as opposed to `NUMERIC` etc).

This can cause some complication, and it may not be obvious at first. For example a column declared as CHAR could have leading or trailing spaces (ex: '  1' or '1  ') and this can spell trouble during data type conversion.

Comment: Can I add that in SQLite, default column affinity is Numeric, but it will accept data of any type (may cause problems of the not obvious type you describe). And that it may be worthwhile changing it from NUMERIC to INTEGER

Comment: @James Thanks for the suggestion, I will keep it in mind for the future but for now I'm sticking with the saying "If it ain't broke, don't fix* it"                             *Potentially Screw it up